# get method returns empty object in angular

Tags: angular

Im using Api and it returns empty object. the console value is {}, my code is given below

**component:**

```js
isValidZipCode() {
  this.appService.getData().subscribe(
    (response: Result) => this.result = response,
    (err) => console.log(err)
  );
  console.log(this.result);
}
```

**service :**

```js
getData(): Observable<Result> {
  return this.http.get<Result('https://www.wsjwine.com/api/address/zipcode/12345');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observable is async. So When u console app out of subscribe you may not still get data from server. You need to do it in subsribe

```
 isValidZipCode(){
    this.appService.getData().subscribe(
     (response: Result) => {
     // do it here
     console.log(this.result);
    },
     (err) => console.log(err)
     );

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your isValidZipCode method as follows

```
isValidZipCode(){
 this.appService.getData().subscribe(
   response => {
     if (response['response'].statusMessage == 'successful') { 
     this.result = response['response']
     console.log(this.result);
     console.log('success') 
     }
    else console.log('error')
  });
}
```